# Not being able to draw a line between labels in flowLayoutPanels in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, draw

I have two flowlayoutpanels, representing columns, ColumnA and ColumnB.
It is a match the column game.

I am trying to let the user draw a line between two labels across from ColumnA to ColumnB.
But I cant seem to get the line to be drawn.

[This is my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaBfr.png)

```
public partial class MatchTest : Form
    {
        private DictionaryNumbers dictionary;
        private Label selectedLabelA = null;
        private Label selectedLabelB = null;

        public MatchTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dictionary = new DictionaryNumbers();
            
        }

        private void InitializePanels()
        {
            dictionary.generateNumbers(7);
            ColumnB.AllowDrop = true;
            ColumnA.AllowDrop = true;
            ColumnB.SuspendLayout();
            ColumnA.SuspendLayout();


            foreach (var kvp in dictionary.myDic)
            {
                int key = kvp.Key;
                string value = kvp.Value;

                Label labelB = new Label
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                    Size = new Size(130, 45),
                    Text = value,
                    ForeColor = Color.Black,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                    BackColor = Color.LightGreen,
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                };

                labelB.DragEnter += LabelBDragEnter;
                labelB.DragDrop += LabelBDragDrop;
                ColumnB.Controls.Add(labelB);
                ColumnB.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            var random = new Random();
            var randomKeys = dictionary.myDic.Keys.OrderBy(k => random.Next()).Take(4).ToList();

            foreach (var key in randomKeys)
            {               
                Label labelA = new Label
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                    Size = new Size(130, 45),
                    Text = key.ToString("D3"),
                    ForeColor = Color.Black,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                };
                labelA.MouseDown += LabelAMouseDown;
                ColumnA.Controls.Add(labelA);
                ColumnA.ResumeLayout(false);
            }
        }
        private void LabelAMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Label labelA = (Label)sender;
            labelA.DoDragDrop(labelA, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
        private void LabelBDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Label)))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }
        private void LabelBDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Label labelB = (Label)sender;
            Label labelA = (Label)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Label));

            // Create a line connecting the two labels.
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            Point pointA = labelA.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
            Point pointB = labelB.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
            g.DrawLine(pen, this.PointToClient(pointA), this.PointToClient(pointB));
           
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ColumnA.Controls.Count == 0) {
                InitializePanels();
            }            
            
        }
    }
```

I cant seem to get the line to draw.
I was thinking maybe I need a picture box?
Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: You should write somewhere the info for where the line is supposed to appear and override the paint and draw the line there

Comment: _Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();_ Anything drawn with this be not be persistent.

Comment: If the Labels are contained by the FORM, then handle the Paint() event of the Form and draw the line from there. You'd need to store the information in pointA and pointB at form level so that it can be accessed after the drag/drop. If you want to have multiple lines then you probably need to create a custom class/structure to hold both points and then have a LIST of that available at form level. Then you'd iterate over that list in the Paint() event and draw all the lines.